# How to uncheck radio buttons after cloning html element with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can't uncheck radio buttons after cloning a html element. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried `.reset()` `.remove()` and `.checked=false` but somehow it doesn't work.

```
<form>
  <fieldset id="firstFieldset">
    <legend>An advertiser wants to know if Shopping ads will appear on YouTube. What should you tell her?</legend>

    <input type="radio" id="firstQuestionFirstOption" name="firstQuestion" value="firstQuestionFirstOption"> Shopping ads can only show on pre-roll video ads on YouTube<br>
    <input type="radio" id="firstQuestionSecondOption" name="firstQuestion" value="firstQuestionSecondOption">Shopping Ads can only appear on Google.com<br>
    <input type="radio" id="firstQuestionThirdOption" name="firstQuestion" value="firstQuestionThirdOption">Shopping ads can appear on Google Search partner websites like YouTube<br>
    <input type="radio" id="firstQuestionFourthOption" name="firstQuestion" value="firstQuestionFourthOption">Shopping Ads can only appear on retail websites<br><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="checkTheAnswerToTheFirstQuestion()">Show answer</button>

    <p id="answerToTheFirstQuestion" onclick="checkTheAnswerToTheFirstQuestion();"></p>

    <script>
      function checkTheAnswerToTheFirstQuestion() {
        if (document.getElementById('firstQuestionThirdOption').checked) {
          document.getElementById('answerToTheFirstQuestion').innerHTML = "The answer is true";
        } else {
          document.getElementById('answerToTheFirstQuestion').innerHTML = "The answer is false";

          var fieldset = document.getElementById("firstFieldset");
          var newFieldset = fieldset.cloneNode(true);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </fieldset>

  document.body.appendChild(newFieldset) = false;
</form>

<br><br>

<input type="button" value="Start again?" onClick="location.href=location.href">
```

Comment: Forget that "document.body.appendChild(newFieldset) = false;" part of the code. It shouldn't be there. Actually I tried document.body.appenChild(newFieldset).checked = false; before.

Comment: Try changing the name

Answer (score 1):

You never actually add the thing you clone to the DOM, but the `.checked = false` method works in my example below. I've used `.disabled = true` since it seems more useful to show the answer you gave in the context of the response for reviewing what you previously answered.

In case I have made a wrong assumption, I left the `.checked = false` part commented.

I also cleaned up some of the radio input elements, as the you can simply set the right answer to "true" instead of having to maintain unique strings for all questions and possible answers.

I also made your function to check for answer more dynamic by allowing to give it the fieldset for the question rather being tied to a particular question.

This should give you a good understanding of adding/removing elements dynamically with JavaScript the way I think you are looking for.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.answerCorrect {
 color: green;
}
.answerIncorrect {
 color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <fieldset id="firstFieldset">
        <legend>An advertiser wants to know if Shopping ads will appear on YouTube. What should you tell her?</legend>
 <input type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false"> Shopping ads can only show on pre-roll video ads on YouTube<br>
        <input type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">Shopping Ads can only appear on Google.com<br>
        <input type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="true">Shopping ads can appear on Google Search partner websites like YouTube<br>
        <input type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">Shopping Ads can only appear on retail websites<br><br>
        <button class="answerButton" type="button" onclick="checkTheAnswer('firstFieldset')">Answer</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<form id="answered">
</form>

<br/>

<input type="button" value="Start again?" onClick="location.href=location.href">

<script>
function checkTheAnswer(fieldsetId) {
 // get a handle on the fieldset we are checking the answer for by its ID
 let fieldset = document.getElementById(fieldsetId)

 // was the checked value in the field set "true" (aka - correct)
 let isCorrect = fieldset.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value === "true"

 // clone the answered fieldset
 let newFieldset = fieldset.cloneNode(true)

 // unset the radio buttons in a cloned fieldset
 //newFieldset.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").checked = false

 // disable the radio buttons in the 'answered' cloned fielset
 let radios = newFieldset.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']")
 radios.forEach(r => r.disabled = true)

 // remove the "Answer" button in the new fieldset
 let answerButton = newFieldset.querySelector("button.answerButton[type='button']")
  newFieldset.removeChild(answerButton)

 // show the answer in the new fieldset
 let answer = document.createElement("p")
 answer.classList.add("answerText")
 answer.classList.add(isCorrect ? "answerCorrect" : "answerIncorrect")
 let answerText = document.createTextNode(`The answer is ${isCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect"}.`)
 answer.appendChild(answerText)
 newFieldset.append(answer)

 // get a handle on the form section used to put the cloned/answered fielsets into
 let formAnswered = document.getElementById('answered')
 
 // append the answered/reset fieldset into the 'answered' form
 formAnswered.appendChild(newFieldset)
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Actually I meant that if a user answers right, it says "the answer is correct". Otherwise it says "the answer is incorrect" and clones that actual fieldset to the end of the form. That cloned fieldset has to be empty and ready to be clickable. Now it's resetting the first fieldset. The title may have been a little misleading..

Comment: @John then my answer still guides you to where you want. You need to append the cloned fieldset where you want it added in your document. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Then simply do what I did to the `newFieldset` instead of `fieldset`

Comment: Am I missing something? document.createElement("FIELDSET");
document.getElementById("newFieldset").appendChild(fld); Should this work?

Comment: @John You have a few options. With `appendChild` it expects a parent container element, if there are existing items there, it will append a new child there. You can use other methods like `insertAdjacentHTML`, too. It just depends on the structure of your HTML and how you want to control things. If you just use the first fieldset and `insertAdjacentHTML`, it will append the cloned fieldset at the top and not as the last thing (so it depends on what you want the behavior to be exactly). I'm updating my answer to suit your use case more specifically, assuming you want the last clone at the end.

Comment: Thank you @forgo ! This is almost what I wanted but it's almost there! The cloning must happen only if answer is incorrect and the cloned fieldset (child) must be ready to answer. The parent fieldset can be disabled after answering but child fieldset not. But I hope I can finish it myself. Thank you very much! I really appreciate this. I have no programming skills at all but I need this so I can create longer form (more questions and options) in the future.